# Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm - Significantly slower than Python

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, map, markov-chains, mapthread

I would like to code a Metropolis Hasting algorithm and thought I would get the general scheme of things going with a toy example.
I think I got it running but my Mathematica code runs significantly slower than a quick Python version I sketched, with just basic vectorised operations. I would really like to hear your feedback on what could be done better. I am sure the difference would be minimal for properly written Mathematica code.

For the toy example, I am simulating the motion of a particle in a double well $ H = -x^2 + x^4$. moving by discrete steps of length *eps*.  The particle starts at the left well $x = -1 / \sqrt{2}$.I am interested in the time it takes the particle to get over the position $x=0$.
I am simulating  two different temperature cases, and I would like to get many different realisations (defined in the variable *nrealis* below).

The code is as follows. I add some comments, would be glad to add more of course.

```
(* auxiliary variables *)
nrealis = 100;
ntemp = 2;
tem = List [0.05, 0.06];
eps = 0.1;
(* energy of the particle *)
energy[x_] := -x^2 + x^4;
(*get a random integer in {-1,0,1} to define next candidate step*)
candMov[] := RandomInteger[ {-1, 1}]*eps;
(*function adding current displacement to picked step*)
candPos[x_, y_] := x + y;
(* calculating Metropolis Hasting transition probability, based on the energy of current and candidate particle position *)
alfa[T_, xOld_, xNew_] := 
 Min[1, Exp[-(1/T)*(energy[xNew] - energy[xOld])]]
(* decide if the step is to be made, by comparing MH transition probability to a value picked from a uniform distribution in (0,1) *)
newPos[beta_, alfa_, xNew_, xOld_] := If[beta < alfa, xNew, xOld];

(*I am interested in the number of iterations for the particle to reach $x=0$ for the first time. The following function applies to the current position, and if it exceeds 0 for the first time it sets the function result to the time counter in the main body of the code. *)

timings[pos_, meta_, time_] := 
 If[pos > 0, If[meta != 0, meta, time], meta]

(* initialising vector of current positions. I try to calculate all the realisations, of which there are ntemp * nrealis, in one go *)
xOld = Table[-1 / Sqrt[2], {i, 1, ntemp*nrealis}];
(*initialising iteration counter*)
time = Table[0, {i, 1, ntemp*nrealis}];
(* initialising results vector, i.e. time for first x >0 excursion *)
metaTime = Table[0, {i, 1, ntemp*nrealis}];
(*create a vector of temperatures to use with MapThread, the first nrealis elements get assigned the first temperature, the second half, the second temperature value*)
tempvec = 
  Table[ tem[[Quotient[i, nrealis] + 1]], {i, 0, ntemp *nrealis - 1}];
(* Main Body
 calculate new candidate positions
 calculate MH transition probabilities
calculate uniform probabilites
decide if to perform transition
update current positions vector
update results vector
continue until all particles have hit 0
*)
Timing[While[MemberQ[metaTime, 0], 
   xNew = MapThread[
     candPos, {Table[candMov[], {i, 1, ntemp*nrealis}], xOld}]; 
   alfas =  MapThread [alfa, {tempvec, xOld, xNew}]; 
   betas =  RandomReal[{0, 1}, ntemp*nrealis]; 
   xOld = MapThread[newPos, {betas, alfas, xNew, xOld}]; 
   metaTime =   MapThread[timings, {xOld, metaTime, time}]; time++];]
```

The Python code (which I would gladly share of course) runs the job with the current temperature values in 1.04 seconds, Mathematica needed 62 seconds.

I would really be grateful for any hints or suggestions, thanks in advance.

**ADDENDUM: Python reference code**

Please find enclosed the Python code I mentioned and used for the comparison. I did not attempt a one-to-one translation. this code is for sure sub-optimal, that is why I was surprised to be a factor 100 slower in Mathematica, in my first attempt. Thanks to the excellent answer a lot of improvements were made, but I am still not matching it (I do not have a C compiler so I cannot use that option in the Compile function, I guess some improvements are to be reaped there as well).

```python
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randrange

def energy (x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    energy = -np.power(x,2) + np.power(x,4)
    return energy

## creating the vector named tempvec in Mathematica ##
def tempInit(nres, T):
    temp = np.zeros(nres * len(T))
    for i in range (len(T)):
        for j in range(nres):
            a = j + nres*(i)
            temp [a] = T[i]
    return temp

## Initial position vector 
def PosInit (nres, ntemp):
    initpos = np.zeros(nres*ntemp) - 1/ np.sqrt(2)
    return initpos

## candidate position ##
def newPos (x,eps, nres, ntemp):
    x = x + np.random.randint(-1,2, size=nres*ntemp) * eps
    return x
## equivalent of NewPos function in Mathematica code (with the alfa and beta vectors calculated internally, differently from Mathematica)

def acceptance(xOld, xNew, T, nres, ntemp):
    energy_old = energy(xOld)
    energy_new = energy (xNew)
    alfa = np.minimum(1, np.exp(-(1/T)*(energy_new-energy_old) ) )
    beta = np.random.uniform(0,1, nres * ntemp )
    xOld = np.where(beta < alfa, xNew, xOld)
    return  xOld

## Main body 
def main (T, nrealis, eps):
    ntemp = len(T)
    poszero = np.zeros(nrealis * ntemp)
    time = np.zeros(nrealis * ntemp)
    metatime = np.zeros(nrealis * ntemp)
    actual = PosInit(nrealis, ntemp)
    tempe = tempInit (nrealis, T)
    while np.any(metatime == 0):
                candidate = newPos(actual,eps, nrealis, ntemp)
                actual = acceptance(actual, candidate, tempe, nrealis, ntemp)
                metatime = np.where(actual > poszero , np.where(metatime !=0, metatime, time), metatime )
                time = time + 1

## Temperature Values ##
temparr = [0.05,0.06]

## Launching run ##
res = main(temparr, 100,0.1)
```

**EDIT**

The final version by HenrikSchumacher is amazingly fast, but I am not entirely sure it does the same computation my naive Python and Mathematica codes, as results are quite different.
Just for completeness I will add a couple of lines to postprocess the results and show the difference.
In short, the escape time over an energetic barrier is simulated at two temperatures, for an ensemble of particles. The barrier height equals the energy difference between $x = -1 / \sqrt{2}$ and $x=0$ and equals $\Delta E = (1/ \sqrt{2})^2  -(1/ \sqrt{2})^4 = 1/4$. On theoretical grounds the expected escape time scales as $\exp {-\Delta E / T}$, for sufficiently low temperatures.
This can be checked by computing the mean of the logarithm of the result vector metaTime for each temperature, and checking their gradient versus $1/T$.
For example with

```
TLowRes = metaTime[[1 ;; nrealis]];
THighRes = metaTime[[nrealis + 1 ;; 2*nrealis]];
LogTLowRes = Log[TLowRes];
LogTHighRes = Log[THighRes];
(Mean[LogTLowRes] - Mean[LogTHighRes]) / (1/tem[[1]] - 1/tem[[2]])
```

I get values reasonably close to 0.25 for both the naive code versions in my post, while I get much lower values for the code in the answer. I am not implying it is wrong of course, mine might well be, I just cannot pinpoint where the difference is, as the general logic seems the same.
Also, the running time should increase with the exponential of the inverse temperature, while it does not seem the case at all.

Comment: There are a few discussions of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm [on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=metropolis%20hastings), as well as [a Wolfram Demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MarkovChainMonteCarloSimulationUsingTheMetropolisAlgorithm/). Have you already reviewed those implementations?

Comment: I have indeed, although i have not yet done tests using some ideas found therein. The fact is, some implementations use inner and outer loops, and I discarded those believing they could not be that performing. I might well be wrong, and I doing further checks, it is just I simply do not have an idea of what could be fast or not in Mathematica. That is why I tried a quick n dirty Python script and was amazed it gave a factor 100 improvement.

Comment: Lots of info on writing efficient programs on these pages: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively?noredirect=1&lq=1   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: and at   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351

Comment: Thank for these links. If it could be of any help to others, these notes could also be very useful, https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/

Comment: @Smerdjakov How we know that you reproduce Python code one to one? Can you give a link to the Python code or just add this code to your post?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I will add the Python code in due course. Have not tried an exact one to one replica in Mathematica, II tried instead to do what I thought efficient, given my relative knowledge. Thanks

Comment: Note that there is a [MetropolisHastingsSequence](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MetropolisHastingsSequence/) ResourceFunction as well.

Comment: And there's some hidden MCMC functionality you might want to look into [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212930/43522) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206756/43522).

Comment: @Smerdjakov It looks like in Python code and Mathematica code have been used  different logics. It is not clear what criteria `x=0` means for random function.  Is it equal `Min[x]=0`, Mean[x]=0`, or `Max[x]=0` in your problem?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I am not so sure I understand what criterion you are referring to, is it the `while np.any(metatime == 0)`  ? That (should) mean, continue as long as any of the elements of the array equals zero, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @Smerdjakov   I am referring to your post where you told something like that  ''I am interested in the time it takes the particle to get over the position x=0. ''  But particle coordinate `x[t]` is random function of time. How did you get the time parameter from this criterium?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the particle starts at approx. -0.7 and gets kicked  about in steps $\pm 0.1$ or stays where it is, every iteration. Escape time equals the minimum amount of iterations needed for the particle to get at x=0. The vector metaTime stores the escape time for each of the "nrealis" particles. Totally analogous to asking how many steps are needed in a particular random walk realisation to get z amount away from the start.

Comment: @Smerdjakov Thank you. I see your point. (+1) for interesting topic.

Comment: Just a hint: you may try `numba`'s `@njit` in python, which may make py more quickly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here a bit of inspiration for you. The following code should be approximately as fast as your Python code.

Preparation:

```
nrealis = 100;
ntemp = 2;
nn = ntemp nrealis;
tem = Developer`ToPackedArray[{0.05, 0.06}];
eps = 0.1;
candmoves = Developer`ToPackedArray[{-eps, 0., eps}];
xInit = ConstantArray[-1./Sqrt[2.], {nn}];
tmp = (-1.)/Developer`ToPackedArray[Table[tem[[Quotient[i, nrealis] + 1]], {i, 0, nn - 1}]];
```

Running the simulation:

```
min = 0;
time = 0;
metaTime = ConstantArray[0, {nn}];
xOld = xInit;
enOld = With[{square = xOld xOld}, (square - 1.) square];
AbsoluteTiming[
 While[min == 0, xNew = RandomChoice[candmoves, nn] + xOld;
   enNew = With[{square = xNew xNew}, (square - 1.) square];
   alfas = Exp[tmp Ramp[Subtract[enNew, enOld]]];
   betas = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, nn];
   With[{λ = UnitStep[Subtract[alphas, betas]]},
     xOld = λ xNew + (1 - λ) xOld;
     enOld = λ enNew + (1 - λ) enOld;
     ];
   metaTime = With[{
       λ = UnitStep[-xOld],
       μ = Unitize[metaTime]
       },
      Subtract[1, λ] (μ metaTime + Subtract[1, μ] time) + λ metaTime
      ];
   min = Min[metaTime];
   ++time
   ];
 ]
```

On my machinge, this takes about 0.3 seconds on average (measured with `RepeatedTiming`). When I take OP's Python code, store it as string in the symbol `code`, and call Python from *Mathematica* with

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", code]
```

it takes 3 seconds on average.

Here some of the crucial steps:

- Use `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` to make sure to work with [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496).
- Don't use `MapThread` if you want to exploit vectorizations (as it is built in, e.g., for `Plus`, `Times`, `Exp`,...)
- Compute energies of each state only once (and reuse them in the next iteration).
- <s>Use `Clip` in order to get a vectorized version of `Min[1,#]&`. (I found this one quite unobvious.)</s> I found out that `Ramp` is more suitable here. In contrast to `Clip`, it is compilable and it probably sets many in input values of `Exp` to `0.`, so that `Exp` can short circuit to return `1.`.
- Use `UnitStep` and `Unitize` to generate 0/1 vectors `λ` and `(1 - λ)` instead of `If` to enable vectorization. (There should actually be a better way to a vectorized `If`, but I don't know any.)

I have not yet used any parallelism here. So there is certainly room for improvement.

You can get out a bit more speed by wrapping the code in `Compile` (and by replacing `-∞` by a really small number):

```
cf = Compile[{{xInit, _Real, 1}, {tmp, _Real, 1}, {eps, _Real}},
   Block[{candmoves, enOld, xOld, enNew, xNew, nn, alphas, betas, 
     metaTime, min, time},
    time = 0;
    min = 0;
    candmoves = {-eps, 0., eps};
    nn = Length[xInit];
    metaTime = Table[0, {nn}];
    xOld = xInit;
    enOld = With[{square = xOld xOld}, (square - 1.) square];
    While[min == 0,
     xNew = RandomChoice[candmoves, nn] + xOld;
     enNew = With[{square = xNew xNew}, (square - 1.) square];
     alphas = Exp[tmp Ramp[Subtract[enNew, enOld]]];
     betas = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, nn];
     With[{λ = UnitStep[Subtract[alphas, betas]]},
       xOld = λ xNew + (1 - λ) xOld;
       enOld = λ enNew + (1 - λ) enOld;
       ];
     metaTime = With[{
         λ = UnitStep[-xOld],
         μ = Unitize[metaTime]
         },
        Subtract[1, λ] (μ metaTime + Subtract[1, μ] time) + λ metaTime
        ];
     min = Min[metaTime];
     ++time
    ];
    metaTime
   ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
cf[xInit, tmp, eps]
```

It is up to 50% faster, but getting the results is a bit more difficult because `CompiledFunctions` can return only a single tensor. However, now that I have remove `Clip`, we can use the options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and `Parallelization -> True` to run several experiments in parallel. On a 4 Core machine as mine, we would just generate 4 datasets like this

```
corecount = 4;
xInit = ConstantArray[-1./Sqrt[2.], {corecount, nn}];
tmp = ConstantArray[
   (-1.)/Developer`ToPackedArray[
     Table[tem[[Quotient[i, nrealis] + 1]], {i, 0, nn - 1}]],
   {4}];
```

and then run

```
 cf[xInit, tmp, eps];
```

The runtime is essentially the same as above, but now four times the data is processed.

**Disclaimer:**

I did not check whether the code does exactly the same thing as yours. So please check carefully and see whether the results are plausible.

Comment: thanks a lot I will be going through this in detail

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: It looks nice but compilation itself takes 10 s on my very fast machine. How we can compare it with Python code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev 10 seconds for compilations you say. That is unexpected. It takes only half a second on my very slow machine. But if this is the first function that is compiled after starting the kernel, a couple of further packages have to be loaded first. Maybe this explains the discrepancy?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Just to further Henrik's point, the first compilation takes ~3s for me from a cold restart, but subsequent compilations take no time at all

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, your latest version is blitzing fast (the version from yesterday was running in 20 secs, this one in less than 1 !)  but the results are puzzling. MetaTime should contain number of iterations per realisation, while it is mainly populated by 1s. I am still going through your code as I have not understood all of it yet, I apologise if I am missing something obvious. Thank you very much very instructive.

Comment: Seems as if, I venture, as soon as one realisation gets $x>0$ and metaTime gets the proper result assigned, all the others get the value of 1, and the while loop condition is over, I will be checking line by line tomorrow

Comment: You used `While[MemberQ[metaTime, 0],...` so the loop stops if all entries of `metaTime` are greate than `0`. So I replaced it by ``While[Min[metaTime] == 0,...`` which is faster. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: But I see now that I have been too careless in updating `metaTime`. Maybe it's better now?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Last version is good one (+1) while I don't understand what problem this code solves:)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Me neither... XD Anyways, thanks for your input!

Comment: @AlexTrounev, this code solves a toy "escape time" case, that is, computes the time needed for a particle to escape an energy well under thermal fluctuations. The general scheme is to be applied to a more interesting scenario.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, the code is really neat and I will accept your answer, really learnt a lot. Yet, it must be doing something different than the original code, and I cannot put my finger on why. I will edit the main post for completeness, to show why the results of your Mathematica implementation are different than what I get my my naive Mathematica code, the Python code, and what is expected on theoretical grounds. Thanks a lot once more

Comment: @Smerdjakov Great!. If you can narrow down what the difference is, I will see what I can do about it.

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Sorry, that was really stupid of me! Anyways, I think this is easy enough to fix (see my latest edit). Of course, the fix works only because the entries of the vector `λ` are either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I think I found the difference. Not that I think anybody was losing their sleep, but for completeness' sake,  I believe this bit is the culprit `xOld = With[{λ = UnitStep[Subtract[alphas, betas]]},
       λ xNew + (1 - λ) xOld
       ];
     enOld = enNew;` The first line decides whether to switch to the new configuration, or keep the old. But immediately afterwards, the energy values are updated regardless, even if the new configuration were discarded. Now results are comparable, also in term of execution speed. even without compiling. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome! =)

Comment: Btw., I fixed the energy update.